# All Items in Items control are dragging together

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

I've been building a dragable nodes tree using items control and the final hurdle is that the children of the nodes, the ones that are in the items control are not able to be dragged separately for some reason.  The root nodes can be dragged on there own so the dragging canvas is working.

This is a picture of the ui, showing the root nodes and the child nodes that are attached together:

[image]

This is the visual tree, it shows that the child nodes are attached to a dragable canvas:

[image]

The code itself is

```
<pnl:DragCanvas>
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Root}"/>
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Root}"/>
</pnl:DragCanvas>
<pnl:DragCanvas x:Name="CurrCanvas">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <pnl:DragCanvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=XPos}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=YPos}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</pnl:DragCanvas>
```

I've got no idea how to fix it and it's really annoying!!

Comment: Now you have enough rep to embed the pictures.